# In-memory data cache architecture for data transfer

Tags: php, database, api, cache

I am writing a cron job to manipulate and transfer remote data.
I need to cache data from a table, process it, merge with previous table, iterate the process, and eventually send the result data to remote database.

Here is a basic in-memory cache storage with thin simple CRUD type API.
It has to store hashes, enforce equal keys and unique ids.
The data come from tables and immediately transformed into hashes (key-value pairs). That way hashes are portable and no reference to tables is needed.
Also they can be easily ported to NoSQLs.

The design is inspired by Parse.com and StackMob.

Somehow I could not find any similar light weight library.
I need it portable to easily transfer to any server.
I would rather avoid any heavy installation or configuration.

An older version [was posted here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/in-memory-data-cache-architecture).

Any critique is welcome.

```
// I am using 'i' as primary key for all hashes
define('ID_KEY', 'i');

/** Local In-Memory Cache: Tables referred by their string names
 * Storing hashes:
 *    all hashes must have ID_KEY as key
 *    all hashes must have keys other than ID_KEY
 *    and hashes in the same table must have the same key structure (enforced)
 * Basic CRUD interface + 'readOne' for the first entry + 'realDelete'
 * arrays packed into json strings, which allows for array values,
 * e.g. array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=> array(1,2,3))
 */
class LocStore {
   // assoc. array('table' => array of keys)
   private $_keys = array();
   // assoc. array of strings indexed by table and id (must be nonempty)
   private $_values = array(); 

   /** create entry, enforce the same keys and new id
    * @param string $table
    * @param ass. array $hash, must have ID_KEY not null, must have other keys
    */
   public function create ($table, array $hash) {
      $id = $hash[ID_KEY];
      if (! $id) throw new Exception('Id is empty');
      unset($hash[ID_KEY]);
      if (! $hash) throw new Exception('Empty hash beside id');
      // sort by keys alphabetically to ensure the same order for all entries
      ksort($hash);
      if ( empty($this->_keys[$table]) ) {
         // first hash for $table - cache keys
         $this->_keys[$table] = array_keys($hash);
      } elseif ($this->_keys[$table] != array_keys($hash)) {
         throw new Exception('Array keys mismatch: '. json_encode($hash) );
      }
      if ( isset($this->_values[$table]) && ! empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) {
         throw new Exception("Id '$id' already exists");
      }
      $this->_values[$table][$id] = json_encode(array_values($hash));
      // for chaining
      return $this;
   }

   // read one entry, empty array if nothing is there
   // reset pointer for iteration
   public function reset ($table) {
      if (! empty($this->_values[$table]) ) {
         reset($this->_values[$table]);         
      }
   }

   // read next hash and advance pointer
   public function readNext ($table) {
      if (empty($this->_values[$table])) return array();
      $id = key($this->_values[$table]);
      next($this->_values[$table]);
      if (! $id) return array ();
      return $this->read($table, $id);    
   }

   // read one entry if there are some or else return empty array
   // in contrast to readNext, the result is always non-empty as long as table has hashes
   public function readOne ($table) {
      if ( empty($this->_values[$table]) ) return array();
      foreach ($this->_values[$table] as $id => $val) {
         return $this->read($table, $id);         
      }
      return array();
   }

   // read by id, empty array if not found
   public function read ($table, $id) {
      if (! $id) throw new Exception('Id is empty');
      if ( empty($this->_values[$table]) || empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) return array();
      //$keys = $this->_toArray($this->_keys[$table]);
      $keys = $this->_keys[$table];
      //$values = $this->_toArray($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      $values = json_decode($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      $result = array_combine($keys, $values);
      $result[ID_KEY] = (string) $id;
      return $result;
   }

   // read and delete one nonempty array or return empty if nothing is left
   public function readDeleteOne ($table) {
      if ( empty($this->_values[$table]) ) return array();
      foreach ($this->_values[$table] as $id => $val) {
         return $this->readDelete($table, $id);         
      }
      return array();
   }

   // read and delete by id, empty array if not found
   public function readDelete ($table, $id) {
      if (! $id) throw new Exception('Id is empty');
      if ( empty($this->_values[$table]) || empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) return array();
      $keys = $this->_keys[$table];
      $values = json_decode($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      $result = array_combine($keys, $values);
      $result[ID_KEY] = (string) $id;
      // deletion is here
      unset($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      return $result;
   }

   // delete by id, exception if not found
   public function delete ($table, $id) {
      if (! $id) throw new Exception('Id is empty');
      if ( empty($this->_values[$table]) || empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) {
         throw new Exception('Deleting non-existant entry');
      }
      unset($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      return $this;
   }

   public function deleteAll ($table) {
      $this->_values[$table] = array();
      return $this;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the (only) method from another class using `reset` and `readNext` (where `$this->_locStore` points to the class `locStore` above):

```
public function loadChains ($table, $mergeTable, $relKey) {
  $this->_locStore->reset($mergeTable);
  while ( $hash = $this->_locStore->readNext($mergeTable) ) {
     $chain = $this->getChain($mergeTable, $hash[ID_KEY], $relKey);
     $hash[$relKey] = $chain;
     $this->_locStore->create($table, $hash);
  }
  $this->_locStore->deleteAll($mergeTable);
}
```

Comment: Actually I can not understand why do you call it ***cache***?

Comment: @zavg Cache is where you store your data temporarily, isn't it?

Comment: Cache is used to store data so that future requests for that data can be served faster.

Comment: @zavg I've seen Laravel calling `Cache` its abstract storage API that can be e.g. database, memcached, redis ... Is this a bad terminology?

Comment: 1) Cache, to me, is something that outlives the request being processed (data stored in files, which can be loaded come the next request). 2) `$hash[ID_KEY]`: what is `ID_KEY`? it seems to me to be a constant, so whenever you call this method, you're using the same key of an array, why, then, are you passing an array?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem 1) Yes, my cache here lives as long as   `locStore` object. 2) Good point, I have put it at the top. It is just a constant I want to keep easily accessible to all code. I am using the same key but the value I get from the `$hash` changes. Is there a better way?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: If your _"cache"_ lives as long as your object, then it isn't cache. PHP is stateless: Objects don't live on in memory once the request has been processed, so come the next request, your object is instantiated once more, and PHP has to do the work all over. Think of cache as a piece of paper. If I were to ask of you to calculate the avg distance between the earth and sun, you'd set to work, and might jot it down, so that whenever someone else asks for the same thing, you can just produce the piece of paper and answer in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Of course, in real life you'd only cache things that are requested more than once every 100 years... but the basic idea of cache is: storing the result of (complex) computations, so that instead of doing the sums over and over, you can do them once, and present the client with the same result whenever it is requested. If done well, the performance benefits are enormous

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ok, I see, so what is a good name for what this code is doing?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: Well, without wanting to be mean, I'd hesitate to call this anything except _"BPP"_ (Bad programming practice). It's sort of a register, but then registers are, generally, static (which is, IMO, BPP, too, as that's just another way of creating globals in drag). You could say that this is just a data-model, too, but then it's not exactly self-documenting (as in: it's unclear what types of data the obejct will contain)... As an asside: the constant `ID_KEY` obviously belongs to the class, so define it as a class constant, please

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for the critics :) The problem is that I want to keep it a global constant available to all my classes. How can I make it a class constant for all classes?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: If it's a constant like `APPLICATION_ROOT` or something, it's perfectly valid to keep it a global constant. That said, class constants are available globally, too: `My\Class::SOME_CONSTANT` can be used anywhere, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Oh I see, I can do it but then instead of `$hash[ID_KEY]` I would have `$hash[Config::ID_KEY]` which would be much longer and not pretty, where the advantages are not clear to me. It is really a very special constant, not one of many.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Is there any BBP other than using a global constant?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: A global constant isn't BPP. If some immutable value is used throughout the code, then a global constant is good. If an immutable value is used by 1 specific class, be it internally, in that class or as an argument to its methods, then a class constant is a better fit (think of `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`, for example). looking at your code (superficially), it would seem that you're trying to make your object behave like an array. That's fine, but PHP offers interfaces to do just that ([the `Traversable` interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)). Look into those

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Indeed, this is a global constant used throughout the code. I've only posted one class here as posting the whole code in one post wouldn't probably fit here. I have looked into Traversable interfaces but these are just interfaces - I still need to write the code. So I don't quite see how they can help.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: All objects that implement the `Traversable` interface can then be used as an array in language constructs like `foreach`, which means you don't have to call methods like `rewind` or `reset`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I have included the only external method using these command (see the edit). How would you propose to change this structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, since there is no answer, I'll write it myself what would have been really a great help and what I have discovered:

The main problem with this code is the usage of many expensive operations responsible for slow execution. It seems the split into keys and values before storing as well as sorting and then re-combining into arrays is really slow.

Why it matters? Because I am running my code using this storage on [Iron.io](http://www.iron.io/)
as [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/worker). Iron is great but has limitations: each worker gets 320 MB memory and 1 hour maximum to run. In the past I hit the memory limit because I stored my data in as **hash of hashes**, i.e. in the form

```
$mainHash = array(
    id1 => array('key1' => 'value1', ... ),
       ...
);
```

with many rows! **Bad idea!**

Then after hitting the memory limit I turned to obsessive memory saving strategy, replacing row hashes by their *JSONs*. However, since all keys are repeated, I considered it a waste of memory to store them on each hash. So I split off keys in a separate array and only stored values! This is exactly what the above code does! Memory usage went nicely under 100 MB! But ... the execution time didn't fit into the 1 hour frame. Which cost me some headache for the few past days until today I had this great idea to try with actual *JSONs*:

```
$mainHash = array(
    id1 => json_encode(array('key1' => 'value1', ... )),
       ...
);
```

And the result is amazing! Memory is under 110 MB and I am inside 1 hour!!!
So only marginal memory loss with huge win to get everything done in one worker!

So here is the winning cleaner solution:

```
class LocStoreFast extends LocStore {
   /** just store json hashes, no enforcement
    * @param string $table
    * @param associative array $hash, must have ID_KEY not null, must have other keys
    */
   public function create ($table, array $hash) {
      $id = $hash[ID_KEY];
      if ( isset($this->_values[$table]) && ! empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) {
         throw new Exception("Id '$id' already exists");
      }
      $this->_values[$table][$id] = json_encode($hash);
   }

    // read by id, empty array if not found
   public function read ($table, $id) {
      if ( ! $id || empty($this->_values[$table]) || empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) return array();
      return json_decode($this->_values[$table][$id], true);
   }

     // read and delete by id, empty array if not found
   public function readDelete ($table, $id) {
      if ( ! $id || empty($this->_values[$table]) || empty($this->_values[$table][$id]) ) return array();
      $result = json_decode($this->_values[$table][$id], true);
      unset($this->_values[$table][$id]);
      return $result;
   }

}
```

Comment: +1 awesome *selfie*! Sorry your question hasn't had more attention. Feel free to accept your own answer!